# Does browser cache HLS and DASH video format?

Tags: google-chrome, http-live-streaming, video.js, mpeg-dash

I am currently studying video streaming and trying to understand how videos are rendered on the web, I would like to know if browsers cache HLS and DASH video format.

Answer (score 1):

Caching behavior is the same as any other resource.  Whether the manifests/playlists and media segments are cached or not is dependent on caching directives in the HTTP response headers, browser configuration, and possibly other factors such as available storage.

You can determine this yourself by using your browser's developer tools to see which network requests are served from cache.